# Write-through cache -- What happens if DB is written, but distributed cache update fails?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, memcached

In a distributed system it is impossible to guarantee that both the distributed DB and the distributed cache will simultaneously get updated on a write-through.

It is possible that DB got updated and then the distributed cache write failed temporarily

- What does the write-through cache respond to the caller in this case? Does it ACK the write or does it FAIL the write? If it FAILS the write is the entry eventually removed from the DB? Does the caller need to worry about idempotency in case of retries?
- Will the write-through cache remember that the write was not updated to the cache and then eventually update the cache?
- Does the write-through cache tail the logs of the DB and go for eventual consistency and update the cache eventually?

How does this all work?

Comment: You might want to check RedisGears write-behind solution.
See: 
https://oss.redis.com/redisgears/examples.html
https://github.com/RedisGears/rgsync